# groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute: java

Tags: java, groovy

```
somebody@myhost /tmp> groovy app.groovy
groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute: java
somebody@myhost
somebody@myhost
somebody@myhost /tmp> java --version
java 14 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
somebody@myhost
somebody@myhost
somebody@myhost /tmp> echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/somebody/.jenv/versions/14
```

Groovy doesn't recognize the symlink. I couldn't find any solutions regarding this. Any pointers?

Comment: When running an executable, the `PATH` variable is searched. But obviously, groovy also wants to have the `JAVA_HOME` variable set.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Did you miss the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` ? It has symlink to the actual path, I don't want to hard code it since I switch it frequently.

Comment: Argh. I missed it. Sorry. Are you able to call `$JAVA_HOME/java --version`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes. It resolves to appropriate path in `fish`. But when I try `bash --login` followed by `echo $JAVA_HOME`, there is no output. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don't want to hard code the `$JAVA_HOME` because I keep on changing it.

Comment: By default groovy invokes a startup file from `~/.groovy/startup` and it looks like you are using `fish` and `jenv`. So you can write: `JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/$(jenv version-name)"` in the startup file which should work smooth as silk even if you change the symlink.